# OpenStack (Microstack) installation issue

Tags: snap, openstack

I'm trying to install openstack on my Virtual Machine, I have been trying this for the last 2 months and already getting tired of trying it out.

What I did so far:

1. ```
   sudo snap install microstack --classic --beta
   ```

   (on Microstack website it says to use `--edge`, on Ubuntu website it says to use `--beta`, I tried also with `--candidate`)
2. ```
   sudo microstack.init
   ```

   (in one of the website it says to include the `--auto`, without including it I am able to configure the DNS, Gateway, and IP)

If I put `--auto` it configures to the IP `10.20.20.1` if I configure manually I specify `192.168.xx.xx` but it doesn't matter how I try it, it will always hang on RabbitMQ.

Do I need to change my router IP Address to `10.20.20.0` to make it work? (I hope not)

Documentation reference:
https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#workstation-deployment

Comment: Hi, have any error shown during the process? Could you check if is possible run the init with some debug options and provide more details where configuration process is blocked? Whit this details is impossible to provide help

Comment: Hi, I ended up finally giving up and went for a manual installation of devstack, I must say that wasn't straightforward also but with some workarounds I was able to do it. Maybe the issue is related to the stack user, when doing it manually the only way I was able to put the user stack into the sudo group was using the root user (sudo wasn't enough) and also some permissions to the directory... I followed the following tutorial doing some small workarounds in the middle: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/single-machine.html

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when you configure edge channel and it does not work, try this.

It works with me.

Replace:

```
$sudo snap install microstack --classic --beta
```

or

```
sudo snap install microstack --classic --edge
```

with:

```
$ sudo snap install microstack --devmode --edge
```

The steps:

1. `$ sudo apt install snapd`   or `$ sudo snap install snap-store`
2. `$ sudo snap install microstack --devmode --edge`
3. `$ sudo microstack.init --auto`

https://microstack.run/docs/

Comment: Hi do you able to deployed using own subnet instead of default 10.20.20.0/24? Tried run microstack.init without --auto...it still no way to edit ip address networking. Interface br-ex created also cannot be edited...cannot find via /etc/network/interface or ovs-vsctl show... does it ovs bridge or ovn bridge? struggle ... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Got this sorted with and installation of rocky/edge channel

```
PATH=/snap/bin:$PATH /snap/bin/microstack.init --auto --control
```

Comment: This shit really works  for me installing microstack on raspberry os... thanks!